# How to send a big email attachment with this PHP script?

Tags: php, email, attachment

I have this PHP script which is supposed to allow me to attach any file to an email. However, it seems that whenever I try to attach a larger file (say, 4mb) with it, I receive the "MAIL ERROR" message. Could someone please help? Are there any settings I can change in php.ini?

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head>
<body><?php

$boundary=md5(time());
$file1 = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('att.zip')));

$msg="
--$boundary
Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h1>This is the HTML mail.</h1>

--$boundary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"att.zip\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment

$file1

--$boundary--";

mail("example@yahoo.com",
     "Testing 4",
     $msg,
     "From: admin@yahoo.com\n".
     "MIME-Version: 1.0\n".
     "Content-type: multipart/mixed;\n    boundary=\"$boundary\"") or die("MAIL ERROR");

?> </body></html>
```

Comment: stop using mail() and start using phpmailer or swiftmailer

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Possible duplicate of a million questions found in the Related section to the bottom right of this page.